Azure Defender for Cloud Workbook
I have only imported existing workbooks from the Defender for Cloud github.
I'm working on a workbook using the below query:
for the main workbook:
let selectedDisplayName = "{DisplayName:dropdown}";
SecurityResources
| where type == 'microsoft.security/assessments'
| extend resourceId=id,
  recommendationId=name,
  recommendationName=properties.displayName,
  source=properties.resourceDetails.Source,
  recommendationState=properties.status.code,
  description=properties.metadata.description,
  assessmentType=properties.metadata.assessmentType,
  remediationDescription=properties.metadata.remediationDescription,
  policyDefinitionId=properties.metadata.policyDefinitionId,
  implementationEffort=properties.metadata.implementationEffort,
  recommendationSeverity=properties.metadata.severity,
  category=properties.metadata.categories,
  userImpact=properties.metadata.userImpact,
  threats=properties.metadata.threats,
  portalLink=properties.links.azurePortal
| where recommendationName == selectedDisplayName or selectedDisplayName == ""
| project tenantId, subscriptionId, resourceId, recommendationName, recommendationId, recommendationState, recommendationSeverity, description, remediationDescription, assessmentType, policyDefinitionId, implementationEffort, userImpact, category, threats, source, portalLink

I also created a Dropdown query:
securityresources 
| where type == 'microsoft.security/assessments' 
| extend DisplayName = properties.displayName
| project DisplayName

I'm getting an error that Query is invalid.  Unfortunately not a lot of information to understand what is wrong.  I searched for some workbook post but did not find much.  Any guidance would be appreciated.
Cheers,
Serge
